# Number of data points to estimate lambda in Box-Cox Transformations in R

Tags: r, forecasting, data-transformation, caret, data-preprocessing

Normally I perform Box-Cox transformations using the `caret` package in R, but when I used the `forecast` package, it gave me different results. I think it's due to the amount of data points used to estimate lambda. Why does `caret` uses only 100 data points by default? Is it better or just quicker?

```
x <- sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = 10:1)
forecast::BoxCox.lambda(x)

# [1] -0.1138864

caret::BoxCoxTrans(x)

# Box-Cox Transformation

# 100 data points used to estimate Lambda

# Input data summary:
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 1.00    2.00    4.00    4.34    7.00   10.00 

# Largest/Smallest: 10 
# Sample Skewness: 0.454 

# Estimated Lambda: 0.3
```

Comment: Have you asked the maintainer of the caret package, or read any relevant references cited in the documentation?

Comment: @Ian_Fin I did try to read [the original paper by Box and Cox](http://pegasus.cc.ucf.edu/~lni/sta6236/BoxCox1964.pdf) but it surpasses my knowledge level. The reason that I posted this question is that I believe it is of general interest.

Comment: What about the author/maintainer? This is potentially just an issue about how one person has chosen to implement an algorithm. That person would be among the first places I'd look for an explanation. If the answer is of general interest then you could always find the answer from them and write it up yourself